# Androidx migration: NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: java, android, androidx

**I am getting this error after migrating to AndroidX.**

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of:
>   Lcom/google/android/aidl/BaseStub;
>           at com.android.installreferrer.api.InstallReferrerClientImpl.startConnection(InstallReferrerClientImpl.java:133)
>           at com.appsflyer.internal.i.ˏ(:30)
>           at com.appsflyer.AppsFlyerLibCore.init(:808)
>           at com.netcore.sales.smartech.NetcoreSalesDemo.onCreate(NetcoreSalesDemo.java:77)
>           at android.app.Instrumentation.callApplicationOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1182)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:6460)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:219)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1859)
>           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
>           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
>           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
>           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)

Comment: Can you show us the source code at NetcoreSalesDemo.java line 77

Comment: I am using the AppsFlyer SDK. AppsFlyerLib.getInstance().init(AF_DEV_KEY, conversionDataListener, getApplicationContext());

Comment: are you using the last update of the sdk ? check this: https://github.com/AppsFlyerSDK/AndroidSampleApp/issues/5

Comment: In migrating to androidx all things is not automatically.I had the same experience when migrating to androidx. Please check all support libraries are not exist. some times in your xml files support libraries may be used.Check all of your code specially top of you files(imports)

Answer (score 8):

I started having the same error when I upgraded `com.android.installreferrer` to version `1.1`. 
Downgrading back to version `1.0` solved the problem.

Comment: indeed.. there is a problem with `AppsFlyer` under v5, but we faced major API changes of v5+ so we could not update any of `AppsFlyer` and `installreferrer` without handling these major changes thou :/